# ubuntu 16.04 does not start after installing some packages

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, gtk, login-screen

I had installed the ubuntu 14.04.4 some months ago and i tried to install the proprietary driver for nvidia and i had problems with black screen, and i could not revert to the previous driver.

So, this week, i installed the ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64.
I tried to install the steam and i had a lot of problems, so i decided to try the proprietary driver, but again it did not work, but i could revert to the previous driver.

While i was installing some packages and installing the gtk+ i noticed that the terminal became strange, the color of the letters changed, the tabs in the settings of the Software & Updates was not separated as before.

Then, I decided to reboot the pc, and the Ubuntu did not reach in the login screen, and was flashing.
I decided to install Ubuntu again, but without formatting, to keep my files, but after installed, i could not start the Ubuntu, then i decided to install Ubuntu again, but formatting.

After installed Ubuntu again i did not try to install the proprietary nvidia driver.
The only driver i installed was the proprietary driver for my processor.
I installed the gtk, glb and pango and the necessaries packages to create programs using the gtk.
Then i noticed that the terminal became strange again, with a different color and a white bar, and i take a screenshoot, i went to the Software & Updates in the settings to check if the tabs are separated, and the same strange thing happened.

I uploaded the [history.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16122370/)(/var/log/apt/) containing the packages i and the Ubuntu installed. 

I upload a [video on youtube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=22wFPUzw9bo) showing what happens when i try to start Ubuntu.

terminal strange, with text color different and this bar:

[image]

software and updates, the tabs are not separated with a "|" as before:

[image]

Comment: When you faced that black screen did you try ctrl+alt+f1 and ctrl+alt+f7 to change virtual console? Any way your last issue is the light-themes you have just installed them. So you can change to another than back from control center > appearance . another way is using Unity tweak tool (search for it in software center) is gives more options to set separate themes for interface, icon ...